# Populating a list inside a for loop with an if condition Java

Tags: java

I am trying to populate a list of integers relating to accounts in a database. However, when I populate it and return it, the list only shows one element. I believe it has to do with the `ownList.add(owner.getId()` being in the scope of the `if`. When I put that statement outside of the if statement in the `for` scope the list is `null`. How should I remedy this to return the full list of account Ids?

Here's my code for that method.

```
public List<Integer>getAllAccountIDs(List<Account>allAccounts) {
        List<Integer>ownList=new ArrayList<>();
        allAccounts=accDao.findAll();
        try (Connection conn =ConnectionUtil.getConnection()){
            String sql = "SELECT id FROM project0.accounts"; 
            Statement stmt =conn.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            
            int accId;
            
            allAccounts =accDao.findAll();
            while (rs.next()) {
                
                accId=rs.getInt("id");
                Account owner=null;
                
                for(int i=0; i <allAccounts.size();i++) {
                    if(allAccounts.get(i).getId()==accId) {
                        owner=allAccounts.get(i);
                        ownList.add(owner.getId());
                    }
                    return ownList; 
                }
            }
        }catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("NO ACCOUNT EXIST FOR OWNER id");
            return null;
        }
        
        return null; 
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Have you run the loop using a debugger to help step through the loop and check the values held by variables?

Answer (score 1):

Your statement `return ownList` is inside for-loop. The function will do what you programmed, that is, return result after the first pass and just after adding the first record.

You might want to move `return` after `for` loop (or after `while`).

Answer (score 0):

The isue is that you `return` after the first iteration of the nested for loop:

```py
for(int i=0; i <allAccounts.size();i++) {
    if(allAccounts.get(i).getId()==accId) {
        owner=allAccounts.get(i);
        ownList.add(owner.getId());
    }
    return ownList;
    ^^^^^^
}
```

Instead of appending a new item after satisfying the condition for `allAccounts.size()`, you add an item once and leave the function

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your function as follows:

```
public List < Integer > getAllAccountIDs(List < Account > allAccounts) {
    List < Integer > ownList = new ArrayList < > ();
    allAccounts = accDao.findAll();
    try (Connection conn = ConnectionUtil.getConnection()) {
        String sql = "SELECT id FROM project0.accounts";
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        int accId;

        allAccounts = accDao.findAll();
        while (rs.next()) {

            accId = rs.getInt("id");
            Account owner = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < allAccounts.size(); i++) {
                if (allAccounts.get(i).getId() == accId) {
                    owner = allAccounts.get(i);
                    ownList.add(owner.getId());
                }

            }
        }
        return ownList;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("NO ACCOUNT EXIST FOR OWNER id");
    }
    return null;
}
```

to make sure that the valid list is returned at the end of `try` block not after the first iteration of your `for-loop`.